# Google Sheet >> Trying to count in sequential

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a set of data, which the value might be repeated and I am attempting to count and mark the counting in sequence.

I am currently trying to create a list using arrayformula (which is a must for my application for some reason), which the list will return the number of times the value is repeated, at the same time indicates the # of the occurrence of that row.

Some thing like the below is what i wish to acc

| DATA | Desired |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1st a |
| b | 1 | 1st b |
| c | 1 | 1st c |
| a | 2 | 2nd a |
| b | 2 | 2nd b |
| a | 3 | 3rd a |
| b | 3 | 3rd b |
| b | 4 | 4th b |

It is a must for me to use a arrayformula or something similar to achieve.
Would appreciate any input. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with;

```
=BYROW (A2:A,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",COUNTA (FILTER(A2:each,A2:each = each)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I get the idea of the formula, but it doesn't work (which caught me curious as well). 

The output I get is instead all 1.

Comment: My bad, I missed the range in filter, I corrected in the post. You can also use COUNTIF inserted of COUNTA and FILTER:. `=BYROW (A2:A,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",COUNTIF (A2:each,each))))
`

Comment: Hi Martin. I have tested both solutions you mentioned and it works perfectly.
Thanks a lot for your comment.

Comment: I'm glad it was useful!